# How to create a file in carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm working on an app that allows users to create custom watermarks for documents. I'd like to  store the watermark images using carrierwave.

So far, the image is being created, but the model.image attribute is not getting created/saved with carrierwave. Help?

```
class Watermark < ActiveRecord::Base

mount_uploader :image, MarkImageUploader
before_save :textToImage
def textToImage
  img = MiniMagick::Image.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/blank.png")
  img.combine_options do |c|
   c.gravity 'Center'
   c.draw "rotate 315 text 50,-375 '#{self.text}'"
   c.font '-*-helvetica-*-r-*-*-125-*-*-*-*-*-*-2'
   c.fill("#dddddd")
 end
 self.image = img
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can assign the file to the carrierwave column in the controller:

```
  @watermark.image =  File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/images/blank.png")
```

and then handle the addition of text in the uploader:

```
process :addText 
  def addText 
    t = model.text
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.combine_options do |cmd|
      cmd.gravity 'Center'
      cmd.fill("lightgray")
      cmd.draw "rotate 325 text 85,-30 '#{t.upcase}'"
      cmd.font "#{Rails.root}/public/images/fonts/Vera.ttf"  
      cmd.pointsize '60' 
    end
    result = img  
  end
end
```